# How do you apply if else statements across user id #?

Tags: r, subset, dummy-variable

I am trying to create a dummy variable that flags the user id of people who attended a specific event. Each user id has multiple rows and I would like this dummy variable to apply to every row of the flagged user id. For example, using the data set below, I would like to flag the user IDs of everyone who attended "event b" (using a "1" for attended event b and "0" for did not attend event b). The tricky part is that I want the 1 to appear in every row that matches the user IDs of the people who attended "event b".

I want to use this dummy variable to eventually subset the data so that I can assess the event attending patterns of the users who attended a particular event.

```
df<-data.frame(id=(100,100,100,101,101,102,102,103,103,103,103),
             event=("a","b","c","b","d","a","c","a","c","d","e"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `ifelse` and `ave`, iterating across `unique` values or `levels` of event

```
for(ev in unique(df$event)) {   # for(ev in levels(df$event)) {
    df[[paste0("event_", ev, "_flag")]] <- with(df, ave(ifelse(event == ev, 1, 0), id, FUN=max))
}

df
#     id event event_a_flag event_b_flag event_c_flag event_d_flag event_e_flag
# 1  100     a            1            1            1            0            0
# 2  100     b            1            1            1            0            0
# 3  100     c            1            1            1            0            0
# 4  101     b            0            1            0            1            0
# 5  101     d            0            1            0            1            0
# 6  102     a            1            0            1            0            0
# 7  102     c            1            0            1            0            0
# 8  103     a            1            0            1            1            1
# 9  103     c            1            0            1            1            1
# 10 103     d            1            0            1            1            1
# 11 103     e            1            0            1            1            1
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to one-hot encode.
You can use the following code with the dummyVars function of the caret package. Afterwards you aggregate the duplicate rows with the corresponding dplyr function.

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(id=c(100,100,100,101,101,102,102,103,103,103,103),
               event=c("a","b","c","b","d","a","c","a","c","d","e"))



dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = df)
trsf <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = df))
aggregate(.~id, trsf, FUN=sum)

   id event.a event.b event.c event.d event.e
1 100       1       1       1       0       0
2 101       0       1       0       1       0
3 102       1       0       1       0       0
4 103       1       0       1       1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm using a way to simple approach. Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(value=1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="event", values_fill=0)
```

returns

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
     id     a     b     c     d     e
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   100     1     1     1     0     0
2   101     0     1     0     1     0
3   102     1     0     1     0     0
4   103     1     0     1     1     1
```